# What is the best method to produce a realtime table in a html page?

Tags: javascript, html, real-time

I have updating data where a HTML table needs to be updated. What's the best framework or approach to follow? View(HTML table) should not be redrawn for small change in a cell, only the changes should be updated. I have been playing around with DataTables but I cant really find any info on this subject. There is [a method here](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnReloadAjax) Ive looked at but this method updates the entire table and can only be called once. I would prefer it to only update the cells that have changed. I'm fairly new to website development.

Comment: What have you tried? Show all the effort you've put into the problem so people can better assist you. If you've not put any effort in, at least take the time to Google for a method to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit this hosted real time [sample ticker application](http://www.fvsg.it/pages/stocks.htm). A real time data updation of Share updates using [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr). I would suggest to use SignalR for best real time server client infrastructure using JS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm building a realtime data visualization project for industrial facilities with a large set of datapoints (>2M). I think, we took the right path with these technologies and frameworks:

- ASP.NET MVC4 (base web app on server side)
- SignalR (for realtime client-server-messaging, great performance with WebSockets!)
- Knockout.js for client side viewModel magic
- CustomMembershipProvider for seamless integration into our existing infrastructure
- KendoUI with customizations for a nice look & feel
- JQuery for a lot of client side tasks

Knockout.js is probably the biggest time-saver in our project, you should definitely take a look at it.